Postgres - How to check if date doesn't exist in result table and if so set data to zero
I have a query that tells me for each client how many devices per month I have assigned.
But I have no entries for the months where there are not devices assigned:

I need to have these rows added like this:
clientId | date         | assigned
11       | 2024-02-01   | 3
11       | 2024-03-01   | 0
11       | 2024-04-01   | 0
11       | 2024-05-01   | 0
11       | 2024-06-01   | 163

This is my query:
select "clientId", date_trunc('month', "tsAssignation"), count("deviceId") as assigned
from "devicesAssignations"
group by "clientId", date_trunc('month', "tsAssignation")

Is there a way to do this?

Could  you please put your data into a fiddle (dbfiddle.uk) - I'll gladly answer then - I'm just not to keen on inputting it myself (time...), plus if you do it then there'll be one point of truth for the question rather than duplicating over many people who might be able to help here - hint you want a LEFT JOIN of a sequence of dates (GENERATE_SERIES) against your table and then COALESCE(assigned, 0) - that should fill in the emply dates with what you want!

Thanks for your help! I did that and got it working!

Here it is. First make a list of all user ids and all months then left join it to your table.
select t.client_id, s::date "Date", coalesce(assigned, 0) assigned
from 
 (
  (select distinct client_id from the_table) cross join 
  generate_series('2024-01-01', '2024-12-01', interval '1 month') as s
 ) as t 
left join the_table 
     on assigned_date = t.s and t.client_id = the_table.client_id
order by t.client_id, "Date";

DB-fiddle demo
